# Can an iOS Shortcut refresh a Safari tab?

Tags: shortcuts-app

Can an iOS Shortcut refresh a specific Safari tab? The idea is to keep a certain webpage on my phone active so that it doesn’t hit a certain timeout feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: Safari > "Open URLs"

If the URL is already open it will refresh the existing tab instead of opening a new one.

Comment: Thanks very much. And I could set that shortcut to run every 25 minutes?

Comment: Yes - there are a number of options for automation, you can see them all in the Automation tab in the Shortcuts App.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed you can set an action for a time but not to repeat it on a time interval, such as once every 25 minutes. Is there any workaround possible to achieve that? Thank you